# Definir nome campo virtual

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tenho o seguinte código no meu model `SubGrupo`:

```
namespace Aplicacao.Core.Dominio
{
    public class SubGrupo
    {
        [Key]
        public int Codigo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório.")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public virtual TipoFormulario TipoFormulario { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Model `TipoFormulario`

```
namespace Aplicacao.Core.Dominio
{
    public class TipoFormulario
    {
        [Key]
        public int Codigo { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório.")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

No caso, a `Key`do model `TipoFormulario` é `Codigo`. Por isso no banco é gerado `TipoFormulario_Codigo`

Como posso definir o nome que será gerado ? Gostaria de nomear a coluna para `TipoFormulario`

Comment: Cadê o resto do *Model*?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Editei

Comment: Beleza. Agora coloque `TipoFormulario` também, por favor.

Comment: Pronto também !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim:

```
namespace Aplicacao.Core.Dominio
{
    public class SubGrupo
    {
        [Key]
        public int Codigo { get; set; }
        [Column("TipoFormulario")]
        [ForeignKey("TipoFormulario")]
        public int TipoFormularioId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo Obrigatório.")]
        public string Descricao { get; set; }

        public virtual TipoFormulario TipoFormulario { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Mas assim ao invés de nomear a existente, eu estarei criando um campo novo, não?

Comment: Não necessariamente. O campo vai existir de qualquer forma. Você só está dizendo pro Entity Framework como quer que seja a chave estrangeira.

Comment: Copiando e colocando o trecho como você digitou, me gerou a coluna "TipoFormulario" e a coluna "TipoFormulario_Codigo"

Comment: Acho que precisa forçar o `[ForeignKey]`. Veja agora.

Comment: Fuincionou, obrigado.